# Async function returns 200 without executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function written in Node JS that accesses data from BigQuery, converts this to CSV and exports to a Google Storage bucket.

Currently it executes and returns a 200, but does not run any of the code within my try/catch.

When testing it just returns:

> Function execution took x ms. Finished with status code: 200

I've attempted to debug by adding console logs at various points, but it doesn't log anything - it just returns a 200.

```
exports.run_checks = (req, res) => {
  "use strict";
  let parsedBody = req.body;
  let startCount = parsedBody.start;
  let endCount = parsedBody.end;
  (async function () {
    try {
      for (let i = startCount; i < endCount; i += 1) {
        //Exclude overly large files here 
        if (i != 100) {
          const query =
            `SELECT *
      FROM \`bq_dataset\`
      WHERE id_number = ${i}`;
          const options = {
            query: query,
            location: "europe-west2",
          };
          const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
          console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
          const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
          let id = rows[0].id;
          const createFile = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(`${id}.csv`);
          const csv = parse(rows, { fields });

          const dataStream = new stream.PassThrough();
          dataStream.push(csv);
          dataStream.push(null);
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Writing ${id} to GCS`);
            dataStream
              .pipe(
                createFile.createWriteStream({
                  resumable: false,
                  validation: false,
                  metadata: { "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=31536000" },
                })
              )
              .on("error", (error) => {
                console.error("Stream failed", error);
                reject(error);
              })
              .on("finish", () => {
                resolve(true);
              });
          });
        }
      }
      res.status(200).send();
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
  })();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is *not* async. The host has no idea that you are still doing something in your function, it returns without any error.

Modify your arrow function to async, and no need for IIFE, remove it, or await it, that is also important!

```
exports.run_checks = async (req, res) => {
  "use strict";
  let parsedBody = req.body;
  let startCount = parsedBody.start;
  let endCount = parsedBody.end;
    try {
      for (let i = startCount; i < endCount; i += 1) {
        //Exclude overly large files here 
        if (i != 100) {
          const query =
            `SELECT *
      FROM \`bq_dataset\`
      WHERE id_number = ${i}`;
          const options = {
            query: query,
            location: "europe-west2",
          };
          const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
          console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);
          const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
          let id = rows[0].id;
          const createFile = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(`${id}.csv`);
          const csv = parse(rows, { fields });

          const dataStream = new stream.PassThrough();
          dataStream.push(csv);
          dataStream.push(null);
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Writing ${id} to GCS`);
            dataStream
              .pipe(
                createFile.createWriteStream({
                  resumable: false,
                  validation: false,
                  metadata: { "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=31536000" },
                })
              )
              .on("error", (error) => {
                console.error("Stream failed", error);
                reject(error);
              })
              .on("finish", () => {
                resolve(true);
              });
          });
        }
      }
      res.status(200).send();
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Have changed this but still seeing the same issue

Comment: @lightfoot34 modified my answer, is this the code you tried?

Comment: Ok I have this working now. I needed to await csv, dataStream and createFile

Comment: Oh, makes sense, I was not aware those are async as well:) Cheers.